# Notation on a Mumford's paper

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

I am reading the paper " D. Mumford. Rational equivalence of $0$-cycles on surfaces. J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 9 (1969) 195 - 204"  and I do not understand a notation in bottom of page 197.  It says: $p^*(\eta_f)=res_{\tilde{S}_0}(\tilde{\omega})$. I am wondering what  $res$ mean? Maybe it is well known symbol and I am not realising it right now. I will be grateful for any help to realise it.

Comment: res is for restriction usually, but I don't have the paper now to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

$\tilde{\omega}$ is a differential form on $\tilde{S}$ and $\tilde{S}_{0}$ is an open subscheme of $\tilde{S}$, so it can only mean restriction.